# Can I use smart watch (Galaxy Gear S3) as just heart rate monitor?

Tags: bluetooth, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I made Bluetooth LE heart rate data advertising application of gear s3 (tizen native application)
my smartphone connect my gear s3 as smart watch not a sensor repeatedly...
I think my smartphone do not recognize my gear s3 as sensor.
I just want use my gear s3 just heart rate sensor!
what should I do?